# send configuration commands with arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, programming

I am using ublox zed F9P multi GNSS module. I have to program it for its configuration messages. Like I have to run a specific configuration of my receiver with the help of Arduino. I know arduino parse the GNSS sentences but can anyone tell me how to write code for ublox configuration commands such that that command can change setting of the receiver upon burning it in Arduino. Also, that code should retain in the receiver even if arduino is disconnected (closing arduino IDE console). Please help

Comment: you write the code using the Arduino IDE

Comment: yes code will be written in arduino IDE.

Comment: You would send the commands over the same serial channel that you read the data from.

Comment: can you give some example of sending these hex bites into Arduino? It will help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you find a **standard** library from arduino.

https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/sparkfun-ublox-arduino-library/

You can find the documentation here:

https://github.com/sparkfun/SparkFun_Ublox_Arduino_Library